# Uncaught TypeError when running PHPUnit

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to run the "phpunit" command from Windows command line in my project folder and having the error message:

Uncaught TypeError: trim() expects parameter to be string, boolean given in phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/sebastian-environment/Console.php:115

For my project I used Symfony and the tests reside in the test\AppBundle\Controller directory.
PHPUnit version: 6.1.1
PHP version: 7.1

PHPUnit responds well to the "phpunit" (from outside my project dir) and "phpunit --version" commands so I suppose I installed it correctly.

Can anyone help what the problem is? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Re-installing phpunit 6.1.2 solved the problem!

Comment: What command are you using to run the tests and which symfony version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Symfony 3.2 and running "phpunit" itself and "phpunit" with the path and name of test file. I have the same error when trying to run them on the DefaultControllerTest.php provided by Symfony.

Comment: Have you modified/deleted the `phpunit.xml.dist` file? Take a look in that file. Have you tried creating an extremely simple test without any dependencies besides `TestCase` with an assertion like `$this->assertTrue(true);` to check if it works?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem in your code. Try replacing the phpunit binary or run `phpunit --self-upgrade`

Comment: @Renan: I haven't modified or deleted the phpunit.xml.dist file. I created just now the extremely simple test found on Symfony website and I have the same error.

Comment: Can you clear your cache with `php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev` without errors?

Comment: @dbrumann: That's an unrecognized option. I'm using the latest version: 6.1.1

Comment: @Renan: Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared

Comment: phpunit suggests it, but it doesn't work for me either. I know it's the current version, but I figured maybe there is some error in your binary. Either that or it's probably some weird quirk from the Windows terminal. Since the error is inside the phpunit.phar it's likely not something in your code.

Comment: @LaszloSimon Given what `dbrumann` said I would try installing the phpunit as a project dependency with composer. You may also try a different version, I'm using version 5.5.*  in a symfony 3.2 project and it works. The simple-phpunit package may help aswell.

Comment: OK, I will try. Thanks for your suggestions Renan and dbrumann.

Comment: Re-installed phpunit version 6.1.2 (released yesterday) and it works!